# Using Deferred to create custom Jquery UI Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to recreate some of the functions of the browser confirm box. We need a custom one for our purpose.

My issue is that the If statement on the button click returns immediately, instead of after the jqConfirm function has received user input and the promise returned.

Any ideas?

```
$('#testbutton').click(function () {
    if (gJs_Confirm('this is a question, are you sure you want to?????')) {
        alert('ok');
    }
    else {
        alert('cancel');
    }
});


function gJs_Confirm(msg) {
    $.when(jqConfirm(msg))
        .then(function () {

            $("#dialog").dialog("close");
            return true;
        })
        .fail(function () {

            $("#dialog").dialog("close");
            return false;
        });
}

function jqConfirm(msg) {

    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    $("#dialog").dialog({
            // autoOpen:  false,
            modal:     true,
            resizable: false,
            height:    140,
            title:     'Confirm',
            buttons:   {
                Ok:     function (e) {
                    deferred.resolve();
                },
                Cancel: function (e) {
                    deferred.reject();
                }
            }
        }).text(msg);

    return deferred.promise();
}
```

html

```
<button ID="testbutton" type="button"></button>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
</div>
```

Comment: You aren't returning anything from `gJs_Confirm`. You probably want to return the promise from your `$.when` statement.

Comment: I'm returning true or false from there. Will that not work? I need to be able to put the gjs_Confirm in an if just like a normal confirm.

Comment: No because you are returning from the callbacks, not the main function.

Comment: Thanks, Would you be able to take a second and answer the question? I don't think I'm far off here.

Comment: @mike c Thanks. Maybe someone who knows the answer Will help out.